# any way to boost the searching stl algorithm in c++?

Tags: c++, search, stl

I am looking a way to search a big array in c++. I google it and someone suggests to use stl algorithm on the sorted the array. I have a big array (nxm) and I have numbers of conditions such that for each search, I will find the indices of ALL data satisfying the conditions and return the indices. I have copied and modified the code I found online as follow

```
struct MyComparator
{
  bool operator()(const pair<NumType, unsigned int> &d1, const pair<NumType, unsigned int> &d2) const
  {
    return d1.first<d2.first;
  }
};

struct LessThan
{
  NumType x;
  LessThan(NumType y) {x=y;}
  bool operator()(const pair<NumType, unsigned int> &d) const {return d.first<x;}
};

struct GreaterEqual
{
  NumType x;
  GreaterEqual(NumType y) {x=y;}
  bool operator()(const pair<NumType, unsigned int> &d) const {return d.first>=x;}
};

void main(void)
{
  std::vector< std::pair<double, unsigned int> > sortData;
  std::vector< unsigned int > allIndex;

  int N=1000, M=2000; // just example, could be as big as 50000
  int P = 2000;       // 2000 conditions, each for one search 

  for (int row=0; row<N; row++)
  {
    for (int col=0; col<M; col++)
    {
      // where x (not shown here) is the data in the array and ind is the correspond index 
      sortData.push_back( make_pair( x, ind) );
    }
  }  
  sort(sortData.begin(), sortData.end(), MyComparator());  // sort the data array

  for (unsigned int k=0; k<P; k++)  // loop the search
  {
     // cond is a predefined array contains P numbers
     double lower_bound = cond(k) - 0.5;
     double upper_bound = cond(k) + 0.5;

     // since the array is sorted, to find all elements satisfying the condition, we search for iterator for the first meet number

     // since the array is sorted, to find all elements satisfying the condition, we search for reverse iterator for the first meet number in the reverse vector
     std::vector< pair<double, unsigned int> >::iterator itb = find_if(sortData.begin(), sortData.end(), GreaterEqual(lower_bound));

    std::vector< pair<double, unsigned int> >::reverse_iterator ite = find_if(sortData.rbegin(), sortData.rend(), LessThan(upper_bound));

    // here, I would like to iterate the data found but I didn't get it compiled, I think it is because itb is iterator and ite is reverse_iterator? so how to make it work?
    std::vector<int> index;
    while (itb!=ite)
    {
      index.push_back(*itb.second);
      itb++;
    } 

    coords.push_back(index);
  }
}
```

In the code, I use one iterator and one reverse_iterator to find the first and last elements satisfying the conditions data>=cond[k]-0.5 && data

Buy the way, I use the while to iterate all found elements and store the second data in pair to another vector. Is that any way to do it with one line instead of using a loop?

This code is faster than my original for-loop code but it is still slow when N, M, P are big. Since I almost has no experience in STL, I don't know if the code I write above is efficient enough. Any suggestion or comments are more than welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: I think you're looking for [std::equal_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range).

Comment: It's also worth nothing as a general rule, if you think you can implement some algorithm more efficiently than STL, you're probably wrong. The various algorithms and data structures in STL have been meticulously optimized. And tested.

Comment: Also, you said "someone suggests to use stl algorithm on the sorted the array". If you have to sort the array and then use a "more efficient" search function, you had might as well do a linear search

Comment: @ user1264727, I don't mean to write some algorithm to beat STL. I mean is there any other STL function will achieve my purpose so I don't have to search it twice. For any other STL structure that will do the search for a group of conditions so I don't have to use the loop.

Comment: like wlyles said, i would probably go for something like remove_if (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/) passing in a suitable predicate. Perhaps you could avoid the data copying by using an iterator pointing to the end of the data that wasnt removed